# Patching class attribute to return different values?

Tags: python, unit-testing, patch, side-effects

Given following production code, where file_path is of pathlib.Path type

```
previous_time = file_path.stat().st_mtime

# recreate the file
.....

if file_path.stat().st_mtime != previous_time:
   # do XXXXX
```

How to patch the Path object in order to cover '# do XXXXX'' execution path?

I have tried to assign a side effect to the st_mtime class member or to assign a PropertyMock(side_effect=[1,33]). No success there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

ok, i have worked around it by saying

```
path_mock.stat.side_effect=[Mock(), Mock()]
```

Comment: This won't work because you can't perform a subtraction operation between two `Mock` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `side_effect` to make the `stat` method return `Mock` objects with different `st_mtime` values:

```
from pathlib import Path
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

file_path = Path('')
with patch('__main__.file_path') as mock_file_path:
    mock_file_path.stat.side_effect = [Mock(st_mtime=1), Mock(st_mtime=33)]

    previous_time = file_path.stat().st_mtime
    if file_path.stat().st_mtime - previous_time:
        print('do XXXXX')
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/WeeklyFrizzyMuse